# Сохранить значение в бд(ace.js)

Tags: php, javascript

Я использую ace.js.И я хочу сделать кнопку, которая будет делиться кодом (например: *editor.com/id=1*). Когда пользователь перейдет на эту страницу (*editor.com/id=1*), он увидит код из db. Этот код db будет идти со страницы, где он сохранял код. Но я не могу взять

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $htmlArea = "<script> 
 var eh = ace.edit('htmlEditor').getValue(); 
 </script>";
 $cssArea = "<script> 
 var ec = ace.edit('cssEditor').getValue();
 </script>";
 $jsArea = "<script> 
 var eb = ace.edit('jsEditor').getValue();
 </script>";
 $insert=$db->query("INSERT INTO `field`(`html_field`, `css_field`, `js_field`) VALUES ('$htmlArea', '$cssArea', '$jsArea')");
} ?>
```

значение `htmlEditor`, `cssEditor` и `js`. Что не так?

Comment: Вы понимаете что написать в php джаваскрипт код и ждать что он заработает - __бессмысленно__?

Comment: @u_mulder а как тогда сделать?

Comment: вопрос настолько большой и общий, что вам стоит для начала поучиться, книги почитать.